# c++ simple function dilemma

Tags: c++, function, return

I am learning c++. Here is my problem:

Simple "calculator" program: read two numbers and a sign, pass them to function calculate, which returns the value or error, if forbiden char input. I came up with two versions of my function and I don't know which is the "right one". Here they are:

First one does print directly, which is not a good practice (is it?).

```
void calculate(int x, int y, char s) {
  switch (s) {
  case ('+'): {
    std::cout << x + y << "\n";
  }
  case ('-'): {
    std::cout << x - y << "\n";
  }
  case ('*'): {
    std::cout << x * y << "\n";
  }
  case ('/'): {
    std::cout << x / y << "\n";
  }
  default: {
    std::cout << "Wrong sign input. Choose on of the following four:+-*/\n";
  }
  }
}
```

Second one does only one job yet, has a flaw: if for example input is '5', '6', and '-' it will return -1 and it will be handled as a mistake by the caller.

```
int calculate(int x, int y, char s) {
  switch (s) {
  case ('+'): {
    return x + y;
  }
  case ('-'): {
    return x - y;
  }
  case ('*'): {
    return x * y;
  }
  case ('/'): {
    return x / y;
  }
  default: {
    return -1;
  }
  }
}
```

What would you do in the given scenario?

Comment: *and it will be handled as a mistake by the caller.* Then fix the caller.  IMHO the second function should be used.  Calculations and printing should be separate.

Comment: Second is best, throw an exception on error.

Comment: Well how to tell -1 result and -1 error?

Comment: Also, you could rewrite your `case`s as `case '+': return x + y;`.

Comment: @KOKO That is what exceptions are for

Comment: @NathanOliver  Exceptions are way back at the tutorial. Not there yet. *sigh*

Comment: @KOKO Do you know what references are?

Comment: And please don't put your cases in round brackets. That's unnecessary. Even the curly ones are unnecessary since you don't declare variables in the blocks.

Comment: @NathanOliver Do you mean something like making a result parameter and alter it instead of returning the result?

Comment: The best practice model validates user input before using it. So write another function called `bool is_valid(int x,int y,char s);` and then only call calculate for valid operations. Remember if `y==0` and `s=='/'` it's also invalid. You might need to check that the result is in range.
Exceptions are for unexpected/predictable errors in programs. They're not a good model for user input.

Comment: @KOKO Yes.  If you can't do exceptions and need the return value for error signaling then you need "result" reference parameter.

Comment: *Well how to tell -1 result and -1 error?* -  You can't. You have the same problem as `std::atoi` and a comparable amount of useful error reporting (pretty-much none). Thus why we use `std::stoi` now. Given that, if you're super early in a tutorial chain the instruction is probably feeding your "good" data until they start covering error detection and recovery. it would be unfairly counterproductive to do otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output and calculation should be separate functions. However, you shouldn’t use a special sentinel value to indicate error if it can also be a valid output value.

The real problem is that *input verification* and calculation should *also* be different functions. I would create an `enum` for potential operations, and pass that in.

```
enum class Operation {
    ADD,
    SUBTRACT,
    MULTIPLY,
    DIVIDE
};
```

Then have `calculate` take in an `Operation`. You still need to validate the input somewhere, but it shouldn’t be in the same place.

You’ll still need a `default` case in `calculate`, because `enum`s can have values other than their declared ones, but since you should be validating the input elsewhere you can make it a simple [`assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert#Example).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the return value to return the result of the operation or a status code, but not both (unless you make use of special values, which I'd avoid.)  How about using the return value for the status, and setting the result in an output argument?

```
int calculate(int x, int y, char s, int & result); // returns: 0 - success; -1 - failure
```

Comment: Output parameters like this are often hard to use, although this could work.

Comment: The inverse is also possible - use the return value for the result, an output parameter for the status - that might be better depending on the use case

Comment: @gcbenison I'd say so. error-code returns risk being silently ignored. It's harder to overlook a required reference. Though not too hard to ignore and throw away...

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of better options.

1. Throw an exception
2. Return `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`
3. Put the actual result in a variable passed by pointer/reference, and use the return value for status

I'd go for exceptions.

```
default:
    throw std::invalid_argument(std::string("invalid operator: ") + s);
```

Comment: 4. Return a different type, 5. `assert` (pretty similar to throwing an exception if KOKO doesn’t know how to `catch` exceptions), 6. *accept* a different type (`enum class Operation`) and do input validation in a separate function. I’d do 6; validation and calculation shouldn’t be the same function.

Comment: I like `enum class Operation`. That makes a much better interface.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's a good idea to separate the computation from outputting the result of the computation.

Coming to the question of how to deal with wrong input ...

Another way to be able to return the status and result will be to use a `std::pair` as the return type.

```
std::pair<bool, int> calculate(int x, int y, char s)
{
   ...
}
```

and make sure to return `{true, result}` for the successful cases and return `{false, 0}` for the unsuccessful cases.

Comment: This looks cool.

Comment: A better solution would be `std::optional`, but your compiler might not support that yet.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

The correct way to handle errors is throws and catches. Here's a version with it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::cerr;
using std::invalid_argument;

int calculate(int, int, char);

int main()
{
    int num1, num2;
    char symbol;
    cin >> num1 >> num2 >> symbol;
    try {
        cout << calculate(num1,num2,symbol) << '\n';
    } catch (const invalid_argument& error) {
        cout << error.what() << '\n';
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int calculate(int x, int y, char s) {
switch (s) {
    case '+':
        return x + y;

    case '-':
        return x - y;

    case '*':
        return x * y;

    case '/':
        return x / y;

    default:
        throw invalid_argument("Received non existing option!");
}
}
```

Also here's a version without throws.

Here's the working version of your code.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::cerr;

int calculate(int, int, char);

int main()
{
    int num1, num2;
    char symbol;
    cin >> num1 >> num2 >> symbol;
    cout << calculate(num1,num2,symbol) << '\n';
    return 0;
}

int calculate(int x, int y, char s) {
switch (s) {
    case '+':
        return x + y;

    case '-':
        return x - y;

    case '*':
        return x * y;

    case '/':
        return x / y;

    default:
        cerr << "Unrecognised option!\n";
        return -1;
}
}
```

I've changed formatting a bit also. Feel free to explore it, if you have any questions related to the code, do ask.

**Answer to the question:** prefer the second way. It's the correct way.

Comment: The problem is this way the function can return -1 even if the input is correct. Also if it goes through default it will print -1?!

Comment: I know, but if the it's the error it'll also say Unrecognised option!

Let's try. 5 6 - gave me a -1. 5 6 ) gave me a Unrecognised option! -1 The correct way to do it is throws but you said that it's way back in your tutorial. For now you can just specify the error message.

Comment: I see your point.

Comment: @KOKO you can check the correct way to do it now. It throws an error upon catching the error that we wanted to. Then I print it with `error.what();` this way we can display the error. This **is** the correct way of error handling. However, as I said for now the 2nd code is fine too. || This time if there's an error it'll just print Received non existing option! nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for the extra effort. Appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't hesitate to ask any questions that you wonder how or why. As long as you follow the rules. Here have a quick tour. Considering that you're new around. https://stackoverflow.com/tour